# Saving and adding up integer values of multiple selections

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, sum

I am attempting to have 10 drop down selections with 3 choices: 1,2, or 3, and save each selection as an integer, then add them all up and have them displayed. I'm not sure how to do this in HTML and would like some help.

This is an example of a selection I have attempted to use (from w3schools), but I don't see how to temporarily store the input as an integer and then use it later.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The optgroup element</h1>

<p>The optgroup tag is used to group related options in a drop-down list:</p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="number">Choose a number:</label>
  <select name="numbers" id="numbers">
    <optgroup label="Numbers">
      <option value="three">3</option>
      <option value="two">2</option>
      <option value="one">1</option>
  </optgroup>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the html you posted is not necessary, all you really need is your selects. The form element is really only used for communicating information from a user to a server. As far as what your HTML should look like:

```
<body>
    <select class="select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

To collect input from multiple selects, as you are describing would use javascript. The following code returns a list of html elements with the class of '.select'.

```
let selectArray = document.querySelectorAll('.select');
```

Next you would want to loop through and add them to a variable.

```
let number = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < selectArray.length; i++){
    number += parseInt(selectArray[i].value);
}
```

There are a few ways to save variables, for your use I recommend using localStorage.

Comment: So I figured out how to print number, but the problem is it prints before the forms are selected. Is there a way to refresh it within the HTML code? Is this where localStorage comes into play? Thanks!

Comment: You do not want to refresh, you want to call an event. Usually this is done with a button. In terms of local storage it is pretty straight forward. "localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');" will set a value where key is a string that points localStorage to the value you saved. the value must be a string. "localStorage.getItem('key');" will return a value that was stored at the key. Note that if you are storing an object you will want to save it as json by doing "JSON.stringify(objectName);". You should check localStorage documentation for more information to suit your needs.